# Does the duration of multiple PlayStation Plus cards stack?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

I bought a PlayStation Plus card for my account. A couple of couple days later, I bought my brother one. I didn't know at the time you can share online accounts. I had two 3 month ones; do I have 6 months of PlayStation Plus?

Do new PSN accounts come with a complimentary online period? If so, how long?

Comment: It's going to depend on user accounts for PSN; are you both using the same PSN account?  If you both applied it to the same account, then yes, it will stack.  If you used separate accounts, then unfortunately not.  Each account will have three months.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you activated both PlayStation Plus memberships separately for you then your brother then the subscriptions will be concurrent on the system.

You would have had to have activated both cards on the same account for them to add on to one another.

As for the second part of your question. Normally the only time there is complementary time is when Sony runs trial promotions, or sometimes they bundle free time in with systems. If you add a purchased time to an account created with trial time the paid time is tacked on to the trial period. Eg, you sign up with a 30-day trial then 1 day into this you pay for a 3 month card and enter the code. You'll have 4 mos of PSN+ before it terminates.

Comment: I should have used that trial period thing :D